# Suma de valores en visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un código con una subrutina y una función. La subrutina la utilizo para cargar los números y la función para sumarlos.
Los parámetros a la función la paso por ByRef pero el resultado me devuelve 0.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
**Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim num1, num2, num3 As UShort
        CargarNumeros(num1, num2, num3)
        Console.WriteLine("La suma de estos numeros es: " & Sumar(num1, num2, num3))
    End Sub

    Sub CargarNumeros(num1, num2, num3)


        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar num1: ")
        num1 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar num2: ")
        num2 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar num3: ")
        num3 = Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Function Sumar(ByRef num1 As UShort, ByRef num2 As UShort, ByRef num3 As UShort) As UShort

        Return num1 + num2 + num3
    End Function**
```

Comment: Por defecto, los datos se pasan por valor, debes poner el ByRef en los argumentos del procedimiento CargarNumeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto, toda variable en .net (sea c#, vb o lo que se sea) se pasa por valor (`ByVal` en VB).

Por lo tanto, cuando pasas esas variables a la función `Sub CargarNumeros(num1, num2, num3)`, no estas pasando las mismas variables, si no una copia de las mismas.

Cuando dentro de ese procedimiento le cargas valores, estas cargando valores a las copias, y cuando volves de ese procedimiento, las variables tiene el mismo valor que tenian originalmente....